# How to use Azure managed identity with Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

In [v11 SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet-legacy) I was able to use managed identity tokens to get access to Azure blob:

```
var token = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token);
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
var blob = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("https://some_storage.blob.core.windows.net/some_container"), storageCredentials);
```

Now I want to switch to [v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) and can't understand how to do the same for `BlobServiceClient`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a sample: https://github.com/juunas11/managedidentity-filesharing/blob/8410ed3f3d4061de7d40531c025bf6e474489135/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityFileSharingDemo/Services/AzureBlobStorageService.cs#L80

Here is how it is used with Azure.Identity:

```
client = new BlobServiceClient(
    new Uri($"https://{_options.AccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"),
    new ManagedIdentityCredential());
```

If you need to run against an Azure Storage account locally, you can use a custom TokenCredential, like here: https://github.com/juunas11/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/blob/3501ee6fff416db7349807e588532da5c3dd24b1/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/Services/DemoService.cs#L45.

Custom TokenCredential: https://github.com/juunas11/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/blob/master/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos/Services/ManagedIdentityStorageTokenCredential.cs.

Usage against Storage Emulator:

```
client = new BlobServiceClient("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

Comment: Will it work for local environment? I mean the sample from my question works in both cases: in azure and locally.

Comment: So in `v12` I can't use `AzureServiceTokenProvider` together with `BlobServiceClient`?  I mean previously I was able to connect to azure blob (not emulator) locally and in azure using the tokens from `AzureServiceTokenProvider`.

Comment: Well, you _can_ through the custom TokenCredential class.